# Update row using equation with 2 rows? PHP Mysqli

Tags: mysql

i need to update a row by doing a subtractions 
e.g

```
t1.n1=t1.n1-t2.n2
```

i tried this

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.field1 = table2.field1 where table1.id = table2.id and triggers
```

i have no idea how ? thanks in advance

Comment: You pretty much have to use the expression you used (`t1.n1=t1.n1-t2.n2 `). What exactly did you try and what error message or unexpected behaviour did you encounter?

Comment: it does not show any error it just not did the equation i searched a little and in many cases said i needed to use triggers or procedures